# Unable to change log format for remote server in rsyslog.conf

Tags: rsyslog

I started working on rsyslog like yesterday so i am very new to this. I am facing a problem. In my rsyslog.conf file i set the file format like this:

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat
```

This shows logs in changed format on my own machine but when i checkout my remote server machine. Logs are getting forward but they are in a different format. How do i show remote machine logs in certain format. Is it even possible to configure that from my client machine?